# I am confused with how to quote quotes

Tags: shell, quoting

Hi I'm abolutely new to bash and coding in general.
I have this screen command that I want to execute. I am already running Minecraft console on the screen "ftb":

```
screen -S ftb -p 0 -X stuff "tellraw @p ["",{"text":"This is a text!","bold":true,"color":"gold"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"More text to be seen here!"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"HAVE SOME TEXT IN UR FACE!","color":"green","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://google.com"}},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"Have Fun!"}]"
```

But the command gets confused with all the quotes.
Ive tried this so far, but no luck...

```
#! /bin/sh

say_this()

{
        screen -S ftb -p 0 -X stuff "$1^M"
}

say_this "tellraw @p ["",{"text":"This is a text!","bold":true,"color":"gold"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"More text to be seen here!"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"HAVE SOME TEXT IN UR FACE!","color":"green","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://google.com"}},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"Have Fun!"}]"
```

Is there a way to encapsulate the command i want to execute in my Minecraft console, so screen ignores all the quotes and just sends and executes the whole command to the minecraft console at the "ftb" screen?

This command should be written and executed in the console:

```
tellraw @p ["",{"text":"This is a text!","bold":true,"color":"gold"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"More text to be seen here!"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"HAVE SOME TEXT IN UR FACE!","color":"green","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://google.com"}},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"Have Fun!"}]
```

Comment: Can you tell us what it is you are trying to send to the minecraft? Are you wanting to send the quote before `tellraw`?

Comment: Yes. the tellraw is part of the command i want to execute in the console and ends with the last quote in the line.

Comment: I did not ask about tellraw, I was asking about the quote before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shell thing not a `screen` thing. You need to put the whole thing in single quotes. The only special character in single quotes is the single quote (it ends the quote).

Therefore, this should word

```
say_this 'message'
```

e.g.

```
say_this 'tellraw @p ["",{"text":"This is a text!","bold":true,"color":"gold"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"More text to be seen here!"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"HAVE SOME TEXT IN UR FACE!","color":"green","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://google.com"}},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"Have Fun!"}]'
```